# setup nodejs on aws ec2 windows server 2016

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016

I have set up an EC2 windows server 2016.

Installed Nodejs.

In my AWS security group, I have added TCP port 80 and source 0.0.0.0/0 for inbound, and all port with source 0.0.0.0/0 for outbound.

When I run my application on port 80, I am able to access it through localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Somehow I can't access it using my static public IP.

Anything I miss out?

Comment: You should probably show us how you start that Node.js app. It's probably bound only to localhost, so it doesn't listen to "external" IP.

Comment: And, obviously, check Windows firewall.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev   Is firewall problem, will update my checklist. Thanks a lot.